# Node js Insert a data in redis via url

Tags: node.js, express, redis, crud

i'm having a problem in posting/inserting a data in my redis database via POST method. By the way i'm using expressjs as framework and here is my code:

```
app.post('/create/:id', function (req, res) {
  return client.set(req.params.id, req.params.val, function (err, data) {
    if (!err) {
      return res.send(data);
    } else {
      return console.log(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Is there any correction here? My goal is to post data like this `http://mydomain:45/create/2/test` is it possible? or do I need only to POST it to /create with the id and the value of that id? Thanks guys. I hope you can help me. :)

Comment: Tip: you should also send back a response when an error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the value of `req.params.id` as the key, and the possibly undefined value of `req.params.val` as the value. You should set the `req.body.val` instead of `req.params.val`, if you are POST-ing with a request body.

Try with the following changes:

```
app.post('/create/:id', function (req, res) {
    return client.set(req.params.id, req.body.val, function (err, data) {
        if (!err) {
            return res.send(data);
        } else {
            return console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
```

And run `POST /create/123` with the body `val=myValue`.